# Missing argument 1 for Teepluss\Theme\Theme::Teepluss\Theme\{closure}()

Tags: laravel, package

i am using a theme manager for la-ravel Teepluss but when i bind any things it gives this error :

Missing argument 1 for Teepluss\Theme\Theme::Teepluss\Theme{closure}()

here is the screenshot of error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwrUd.png

just adding this line $this->theme->bind('active', 'home'); to the below code gives error

```
public function showWelcome()
    {
        $this->theme->layout('default');
        $this->theme->setTitle($this->config['SEO']['home']['title']);
        $this->theme->setMeta_desc($this->config['SEO']['home']['meta_description']);
        $this->theme->setMeta_keywords($this->config['SEO']['home']['meta_keywords']);

        $this->theme->bind('active', 'home');

        return $this->theme->scope('home.index')->render();
    }
```

i think the package theme binding has some issues

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the issue. There is bug in this package. There shouldn't be any argument in the clouser and the code should be something like this :

```
public function bind($variable, $callback = null)
    {
        $name = 'bind.'.$variable;

        // If callback pass, so put in a queue.
        if ( ! empty($callback))
        {
            // Preparing callback in to queues.
            $this->events->listen($name, function() use ($callback, $variable)
            {
                return ($callback instanceof Closure) ? $callback() : $callback;
            });
        }

        // Passing variable to closure.
        $_events   =& $this->events;
        $_bindings =& $this->bindings;

        // Buffer processes to save request.
        return array_get($this->bindings, $name, function() use (&$_events, &$_bindings, $name)
        {
            $response = current($_events->fire($name));

            array_set($_bindings, $name, $response);

            return $response;
        });
    }
```